# Stub nodejs proxyquire return error :TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, es6-promise, sinon-chai, proxyquire

My unit test case is failing, I am getting an error message

> 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined'.

It seems issue with config file which have url property. Please someone help me on same.

```js
// Employee.js

const config = require('../../config/config');
const api = require('./api');

class Employee {
  constructor() {
  }

  getEmp() {
    return api.post({
      url: config.url,
    });
  }
}
module.exports = Employee;

//Employee.test.js
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised).should();
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
describe('Test', function () {
  let myController;
  let sandbox;
  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    myController = proxyquire('../src/Employee.js', { 'config': {}, 'api': {} });

  });
  afterEach(function afterEach() {
    sandbox.restore();
  });
  it('my Test', (done) => {

    let controller = new myController();
    controller.getEmp()
            .then(response => {
              console.log('its me ' + response);
              done();
            });
  });
});
```